# Вывод списка брендов категории woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Есть сайт с каталогом товаров, в котором при переходе на страницу категории товаров, нужно сделать вывод по брендам.
По умолчанию woocommerce показывает страницу категории со всеми товарами на ней. А нужно, чтобы появлялся список брендов с картинкой и числом товаров бренда. А уже затем при выборе бренда происходил переход на страницу категории. 
В Ву я новичок, максимум могу поставить и настроить его. Как решить данную задачу? Есть ли бесплатный плагин для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи.
Вообще, поиском Яндкса ("гуглить" уже не модно) воспользовавшись, можно легко найти множество нужных плагинов для woocommerce, в том числе и для списка компаний-производителей. Один из них разработан woocommerce, так и называется "WooCommerce brands".
Но лучше, на моё мнение, [Perfect Woocommerce Brands](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/perfect-woocommerce-brands/) -

Описание на русском.
Так же, в качестве "брендов" можно использовать МЕТКИ товаров и по ним фильтровать.
Можно общую категорию товара с "БРЕНДАМИ" создать, и из неё выводить категории первые дочерние на главную. Так вообще будет просто и правильно.